# How to quick built eps and pdf in same document

Tags: pdf, pdfpages, eps

I am writing my thesis, using .eps files for the images. I also need to append pdf pages, but all that I have as result (for the PDF files) are empty numbered pages.

I include the figures as in the following example:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{images/linearActuator.eps}
\caption[Linear actuator structure]{General linear actuator structure \cite{xxx}}
\label{Fig:linearActuator}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

They're more than 80, so changing every one of them isn't an option.

I try to attach the PDF mechanical drawings from a new chapter:

```
\chapter{Mechanical drawings of the proposed structure} \label{App:draws}
\captionsetup{belowskip=1pt,aboveskip=1pt}

\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand=\thispagestyle{plain}]{Appendices/images/FullRobotPieces.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand=\thispagestyle{plain},angle=90]{Appendices/images/caderaAssembly.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand=\thispagestyle{plain}]{Appendices/images/caderaMobAssembly.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand=\thispagestyle{plain}]{Appendices/images/legLeft.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand=\thispagestyle{plain}]{Appendices/images/calf.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand=\thispagestyle{plain}]{Appendices/images/leftFoot.pdf}
```

The master code is this one:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[tmargin=3cm, lmargin=3cm, rmargin=2cm, bmargin=3cm]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{csquotes}
%\geometry{} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float} 
%\usepackage{subfigure}  
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts,latexsym,bm,eucal}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,lined,boxed,figure]{algorithm2e}

\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric-comp,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\usepackage{xr} % Referenciar entre capítulos de documentos distintos
\usepackage{pslatex} 
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[full]{textcomp}   
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}

\usepackage{pstricks} %dibujos en pstricks
%\usepackage{pstcol} % para color
\usepackage{pst-node} % para diagramas
\usepackage{pst-plot} % para representacion de datos funciones, etc
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pst-coil}
                              
\usepackage[justification=centering,font={small,it},skip=5pt]{caption}

\usepackage{subcaption} %modificar los pies de foto

\usepackage{multicol}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}                                                     
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nosep}

\usepackage{lscape}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\paragraph}
{\normalfont\it}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex} 

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{breakurl} % Para cortar las direcciones largas, siempre debe ir después de hyperref
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{pdfpages} % insertar pdfs en el documento

%===============================================================================

\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\newcommand{\grad}{$^{\circ} $}
\newcommand{\regs}{\textsuperscript{\textregistered}}
\newcommand{\dint}{\displaystyle\int}
\newcommand{\registered}{\textsuperscript{\textregistered}}
\newcommand{\dsum} {\displaystyle\sum}
\newcommand{\dprod} {\displaystyle\prod}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\cleardoublepage}{ \clearpage\ifodd\c@page\else
\hbox{} \vspace*{\fill} \thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage
\fi }
\makeatother
\makeindex
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}
\addbibresource{publications.bib}
%
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\usepackage[toc,automake]{glossaries-extra}
\setabbreviationstyle{long-short-user}
%%\setacronymstyle{long-short}
\makeglossaries
%%\makenoidxglossaries
\loadglsentries{glossary}
\usepackage{glossary-mcols}
\usepackage{setspace} % Ajustar interlineado

%\newcommand{\citep}{\cite}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibcompletename}[1]{%
  \ifitemannotation{highlight}
    {\textbf{#1}}
    {#1}%
} % Pone mi nombre en negritas

% =============================================================================================
\begin{document}
\include{Portada/Portada}
\cleardoublepage
\include{Portada/Cover}
\cleardoublepage    
\include{Agradecimientos/Acknowledgement.tex}
\cleardoublepage
\cleardoublepage
\pagestyle{fancy}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\cleardoublepage
\include{Abstract/resumen}
\cleardoublepage
\include{Abstract/abstract}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\listoffigures
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Index of Figures}
\cleardoublepage
\listoftables
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Index of Tables}
\cleardoublepage
\printunsrtglossary[title={Acronyms},toctitle={Acronyms used},style={index},style=mcolindex]
\cleardoublepage
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\onehalfspace
\include{Antecedents/Antecedents}
\include{MathematicalModel/MathematicalModel}
\include{Controller/Controller}
\include{ReinforcementL/ReinforcementL}
\include{MechanicalModel/MechanicalModel}
\include{Conclusions/Conclusions}
\include{Conclusions/Publications}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}
\printbibliography
\appendix
\include{Appendices/Drawing}
\newpage
\end{document}
```

I use *MiKTeX 4.8* with *Texmaker* to build the document with:

**LaTeX** + **Bib(la)tex** + **LaTeX (x2)** + **dvips** + **ps2pdf**

What am I doing wrong?

Update: using pdflatex results in error: "shell escape" (or "write18") is not enabled:
auto-pst-pdf will not work!

Comment: Post a minimal working example showing the problem. What you post is not minimal (many parts of the preamble are unrelated with the problem) and it is not compilable (we not have your includes). Said that, some specific reason to use the prehistoric  tex → dvi → pdf workflow? Try with pdflatex + biber + pdflatex  + pdflatex.

Comment: You could use lualatex or pdflatex. The graphics driver for these TeX-engines include epstopdf automatically, and you don't need to convert your eps manually.